# Aurelia/Bootstrap: Making a dropdown menu in a nav bar when routing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I'm trying to implement a Bootstrap dropdown menu in a [nav bar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) in an [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) application. I'm using rather standard Bootstrap code, nothing too fancy at this point.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    ...
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Artists
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#/artists">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/artists/incomplete">Incomplete</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is `href="#"` in the menu header item. I have a router and a route for `#`. When I click on the link, it goes to that route. No big surprise, but that's clearly not what I want to do; I want to display my dropdown menu.

I don't know what to do here. `href=""` causes the application to refresh. Putting a fake route in there throws an error on the JavaScript side and still doesn't show the menu.

Comment: What did you mean with "I have a router for `#`"? Your code works fine for me

Comment: Here is my app.js:

    export class App {
      configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.title = 'Song Charts';
        config.map([
          { route: ['','welcome'],   name: 'welcome', moduleId: 'welcome', title: 'Welcome' },
          { route: 'artists',        name: 'artists', moduleId: 'artists', title: 'Artists' },
          { route: 'artists/incomplete', name: 'incomplete-artists', moduleId: 'incomplete-artists', title: 'Incomplete Artists' },
        ...
        this.router = router;
      }
    }

Comment: You could use another element than a, and don´t use the `href` attribute.

Comment: This uses Bootstrap. `button` messes up the formatting.

Comment: I thought bootstrap's javascript stopped propagation on the click event to keep stuff like that from happening. Are other bootstrap functions working (e.g. tooltips)?

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

to your main file.